# How can I debug my specific version of an open-source lib when there's a maven dependency for a previous version of that lib

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi, classpath, pdfbox

I have a Java application for which I'm using PDFBox; the latest stable release of PDFBox is 2.0.25. I want to step through PDFBox code after my project calls it.

I have downloaded the PDFBox source, imported it as a Maven project into an eclipse workspace, and put that project on the build path for the application project. I removed the PDFBox dependency from the pom.xml for my application, and did Maven update and clean rebuild for things.

However, another part of my application uses POI, and it also depends on PDFBox, specifically 2.0.24. So the PDFBox 2.0.24 jar is in the 'referenced libraries' for the application, and I've verified that sometimes, when a PDFBox reference is made, it uses the 2.0.24 from the referenced libraries instead of my local 2.0.25 library.

Obviously in strict classpath terms this is problematic -- a classloader will run down the list of available full pathnames until it finds one, and it isn't evaluating library versions. I know this can theoretically be done, on a runtime level, with classloaders, but don't know how to apply that in my situation. How can this get resolved correctly in the general case? The general case wouldn't have to be a debugging situation, it could be 2 (or more) libraries attempting to use different versions of a common library just to get their work done.

In my current situation, I've tried putting a PDFBox dependency before the POI dependency in the dependency list in the pom.xml. I don't know any other way to influence which jar the runtime might use. Is there some way to specify that the POI code use a different classloader or something?

Comment: Why do you need the PDFbox source code as a full fledged project? Maven can download the source code for the dependencies, and if you debug your project and you step into PDFbox code, you should be able to step through it. No need to have it as project locally. This should also solve your versioning problems.

Comment: @dunni First of all, it would only solve my versioning problems if I wanted to use the same version as the library uses. I would rather use the current version. Second, this is a general problem and question, i.e., not just about this specific situation. Same type of problem exists if I want to use two libraries which depend on different versions of a third library.

Comment: Ok, but i still don't understand the real problem. If you have 2 libraries, which depend on different versions of the third library, in your application runtime classpath you only end up with one version of the third library, and that's the one you want to debug, right? Maven will not put both versions of the 3rd party library in the resulting classpath.

Comment: The reason why i'm asking for clarification is, that your question currently sounds to me like an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: I want to use two libraries in my application, PDFBox (so I can do some things with PDFs) and POI (so I can do some things with Word docs). I want to use the current version of PDFBox, to have the latest code and security fixes or whatever. The pom.xml for the current version of POI, however, specifies a previous version of PDFBox. So it puts the previous version on the classpath, and I cannot step through current-version source with it, as it is not the version being used.

Comment: But it should only put the previous version on the classpath in the case, where you removed the direct dependency to PDFBox and added it as project. Otherwise Maven should resolve both versions and only put one on the classpath. You could check that with `mvn dependency:tree`. The older PDFBox version, which is brought in by POI, should then have a remark like "omitted for conflict with...".

Comment: If that doesn't work, then you have a problem with Maven (or the Eclipse integration), because Maven is able to deal with such situations and will resolve it usually correctly.

Comment: So, if instead of making it an eclipse project, I just put a dependency in my application pom for the current version, it won't load the previous version? What happens when the POI library calls a method that has changed (or been deleted) in the new version? If Maven just fails to load it, I don't understand why there aren't failed applications all over the place. This would also mean it is not possible to change the library,

Comment: Correct, Maven will use the version that you put directly as dependency. If POI doesn't work with this version, then you have to downgrade your version to make it work. Maven doesn't "fail" to load it, this is expected behaviour (since you cannot have 2 versions of the same library on the classpath, as you already noticed). Not sure what you mean with your last sentence.

Comment: ok, thanks -- I do not understand how large modern applications deal with this in general. POI loaded 61 libraries as maven dependencies, I don't see how an application with a list of dependencies of any size keeps from having version conflicts. And I can downgrade my own use in this case; when the conflict is between two libraries you want to use, that isn't possible. I figured since we have this tool for managing the elaborate dependencies we end up with, that someone had used classloaders or something so the actual dependencies could be honored. Thanks for the help.

Comment: From experience i can tell you, that version and dependency management can be a pain in large projects. But if you hit indeed a point where you need two different versions, then creating a separate application for a specific usecase is usually easier than managing classloaders within an application.

Comment: You can also exclude (see "<exclusions>" ) the 2.0.24 dependency in the POI dependency segment of the pom.xml.

Comment: I've added the PDFBox dependency to POI because of PPT/WMF/EMF rendering and we usually upgrade that dependency. So no need to downgrade in your case, as you don't use that feature anyway. The heap of other dependencies come from Batik. Look at the 5.2.0 pom.xml and you'll see a lot of optional dependencies. Exclude those and run your tests. Also in the JPMS context, those are marked static/optional.